# Is it normal for the ViewModel class to be called without setValue on LiveData?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I am studying the `MVVM` pattern.

I have a question regarding `LiveData` while using `ViewModel class`.

Even if I do not change the value of `LiveData` with `setValue` or `postValue`, it continues to `observe` and execute the fragment.

When `addRoutine()` is called, `vm.observe` also continues to run.

As you can see there is no `setValue` or `postValue` in `addRoutine()`, so `LiveData` has no value change at all.

But why does `vm.observe` keep running?

This is my code.

**ViewModel.kt**

```
class WriteRoutineViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _items: MutableLiveData<List<RoutineModel>> = MutableLiveData(listOf())
    private val rmList = arrayListOf<RoutineModel>()

    val items: LiveData<List<RoutineModel>> = _items

    fun addRoutine(workout: String) {
        val rmItem = RoutineModel(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), workout, "TEST")
        rmItem.getSubItemList().add(RoutineDetailModel("2","3","3123"))
        rmList.add(rmItem)

//        _items.postValue(rmList)
    }

    fun getListItems() : List<RoutineItem> {
        val listItems = arrayListOf<RoutineItem>()

        for(testRM in rmList) {
            listItems.add(RoutineItem.RoutineModel(testRM.id,testRM.workout,testRM.unit))

            val childListItems = testRM.getSubItemList().map { detail ->
                RoutineItem.DetailModel("2","23","55")
            }
            listItems.addAll(childListItems)
        }
        return listItems
    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
class WriteRoutineFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding : FragmentWriteRoutineBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private val vm : WriteRoutineViewModel by viewModels { WriteRoutineViewModelFactory() }
    private lateinit var epoxyController : RoutineItemController

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,
                              container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        _binding = FragmentWriteRoutineBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        getTabPageResult()

        // RecyclerView(Epoxy) Update
        vm.items.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { updatedItems ->
            epoxyController.setData(vm.getListItems())
        }
    }

    private fun getTabPageResult() {
        val navController = findNavController()
        navController.currentBackStackEntry?.also { stack ->
            stack.savedStateHandle.getLiveData<String>("workout")?.observe(
                viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { result ->
                    vm.addRoutine(result)
                    stack.savedStateHandle?.remove<String>("workout")
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `vm.getListItems()`?

Comment: sorry. It's edited it

Comment: In case you didn't know. It's normal that it's called 1 time, even when the value is not set. The observer is always called right after the observe to get the initial value, even if it's null

Comment: As @IvoBeckers said, `onChanged` will be called at least once if the `LiveData` has an initial value. If you don't want the `onChanged` called for the first run, you can remove `listOf()` from the `LiveData` constructor.

Comment: @IvoBeckers So you mean `vm.items.observe() { }` is always called at least once to get the initial value, whether `items` have a value or not (even if it's `null`)?
Even if the value of `items` does not change?

Comment: @BernhardJosephus 
Ummm, I'm sorry, I don't understand exactly.

Comment: "So you mean vm.items.observe() { } is always called at least once..." I think you already got the point here. Just want to make it clear for this point "...whether items have a value or not (even if it's null)?" If the items do not have a value, then `onChanged` won't be called. NULL is considered as a value. So, if you don't want the `onChanged` to be called for the first time, you can set it to `MutableLiveData()` <- no initial value. Hope it clears!

Comment: Well, I half understood and half didn't. Because in my code, I put a `break point` in `vm.items.observe() { }` and tried to execute it.

The result is that whenever `vm.addRoutine()` is executed, the `breakpoint` is stopped in `vm.items`.
(In `addRoutine()`, `postValue` is commented out.)

I do `postValue` but `LiveData` doesn't change, how does `observe` work?
For reference, the function of the current code is to execute `addRoutine()` after receiving data after switching from the current fragment to another fragment.
This action may be repeated multiple times depending on the user.